# Pipelining in C with at least 3 child processes

Tags: c, pipeline

I tried finding examples of pipe lining in C but couldn't find any example that pipe lines more than 2 child processes. My code is working fine with two processes but I can't understand at all how to extend it to three processes. Please help with an example.

Comment: As given, it's not entirely clear what as to what exactly you're trying to do. Are you talking about doing something like `foo | bar | baz`? It so, all you need to do is loop through every adjacent pair of children and pipeline them together as with just 2 children.

Comment: Yes I mean that only. I have been trying to do the same but unable to. i would really appreciate if i could see an example because i need to extend it to accept any number of arguments.. :(